# Unable to get vm-list for KVM using nrpe check

Tags: bash, kvm-virtualization, nagios, nrpe

I created check in KVM virtualized host to get list of available VM's in KVM hypervisor using below command.

```
$ cat /usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_kvm
#!/bin/sh
val=`virsh list --all | sed '1,2d' | sed '/^$/d'| awk '{print $2":"$3}'`
echo "VM List is" - $val
exit 0
```

Executing the script locally fetch the data as below.

```
# sh /usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_kvm

VM List is - oy06b:running .......
```

While, fetching the data from nagios server using nrpe, I am unable to get VM list. 
I am getting as below "VM List is" and $val is not showing.

```
/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_nrpe -H <Host IP> -c check_kvm

VM List is -
```

Please advice....

Comment: Please show what the desired output should be. Your line can simply be converted to `virsh list --all | awk 'NR>2 && NF{print $2":"$3}'`  No need for sed there. virsh also has the `virsh list --all --name --state-shutoff --state-running` etc...

Answer (score 1):

Executing the tool `virsh` requires root privileges and this is what you are actually doing when executing it directly from the shell.

However, it is executed as `nagios` user when run via NRPE daemon. To fix this, you need to add `sudo` to command definition in `nrpe.cfg`:

```
command[check_kvm]=sudo /usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_kvm
```

And add `nagios` user to sudoers file to allow executing this command/script without asking for a password:

```
nagios  ALL = NOPASSWD: /usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_kvm
```

Comment: yes, it is working now. Ty....

Comment: @JeffJose: If the answer was useful, you can accept it :)

Comment: A better option is to make the call to virsh go through sudo, rather than the entire plugin.

Comment: @Keith: In any case, you need to add nagios user to sudoers file.